# This page is downloaded when the site is visited

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, safari

Try to open it with Safari or IE

webtelevideo.com

Chrome has no problems

What does it depend?

Comment: Please tell us about the problems rather than asking us to figure out what they are. At the moment this isn't really a very good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The server does not identify the page as HTML:

```
Content-Type: text-html;charset=UTF-8
```

The appropriate MIME type is `text/html`, not `text-html`. It's a serious server misconfiguration.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm happily married :)

Comment: hey where/what file are you supposed to change? how to check the content-type?

Answer (score 0):

as Álvaro G. Vicario stated, the w3c validator indicates between other things:

The document is being served with the text-html Mime Type which is not a registered media type for the Document Type. The recommended media type for this document is: application/xhtml+xml

i suggest you to valide your site structure through http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of the apache configuration try adding

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Answer (score -1):

Got absolutely no idea what exactly you're position is with this... Are you the developer? I assume not, however, unable to load in IE, until I changed the URL to: http://www.webtelevideo.com/Programmi-TV/Martin - May work with other things, but up to you to check.

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, but this isn't an answer.  Something like this you should put as a comment to the question

Comment: Duly noted, and I'll make more use of the comments field, bearing in mind, I've just registered, however, there wasn't a real question which was understood properly in English. I thought the guy who posted that was just wanting to view the Website someone else made. Can you remove my down point please?